# Can I read json file from resources in shared kotlin multiparform code?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I have a shared module in kotlin multiplatform project which contains shared code for all platforms.
I wish to put there a json file (string-resources.json) for examle, I've put it to

```
shared\src\commonMain\resources\string-resources.json
```

Now I need to read contents on this file, so it would work on every platform (android, ios, etc...). So something like this:

```
class JsonStringResource {

    companion object {
        fun get(key: String) {
            val classLoader = JsonStringResource::class.java.classLoader
            val resource = classLoader.getResource("strings-test.json").getText()
            println(resource)
        }
    }

}
```

Is it possible? The code above doesn't work since getResource always returns null (even if I tried putting it as expected-actual class and putting above  implementation to Android only)

Comment: KMM doesn't support it out of the box, check out on [moko-resources](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources)

Comment: see this:
 https://medium.com/arconsis/reading-local-json-files-in-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-kmm-2538e9792c70